# Angular 2 doesn't output errors to console

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular 2 and I don't get any errors in the console. I've followed the tour of hero's tutorial, and anytime I screw up there is no error either in the TS console or the chrome console. Is there something that I am doing wrong? I have followed the Tour of Hero's tutorial to the letter.

Comment: It's very strange. Could you describe firsts step, how do you run application? Additionaly, you can make some screens from browser with console. It will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: May be you are not screwing up anything ;) . Please share your code snippets and screenshots .

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to display the errors? Are you using console.log() in the typescript component to display? If yes, that should work. Please post the example that you are trying. Will take a look.